# Website suddenly loads VERY slow with SSL

Tags: ssl, wordpress, website, slow-connection

I am using WordPress.

I've been using the free SSL from Hostgator from Let's encrypt. A few days ago my website started to load very very slow which results in a significant decrease in website traffic. The website loads ok in HTTP but very slow in HTTPS. I 've tried the paid SSL from comodo and reinstalled the certificate but that didn't fix, I've also tried to deactivate all my plugins, firewall, one by one, but none would work. According to the Google developer tool, most of the loading time was stocked in the "SSL and initial connection" session (as demonstrated in the image). I am getting really frustrated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Btw, My domain name is https://smartbuy.space/

Answer (score 0):

Its rather a wesite load time issue .. you can improve site loading by enabling caching , gzip compression, image optimization etc.. have a look at https://gtmetrix.com/reports/smartbuy.space/IgwEU5Dr

your site is struggling in so many areas.

[image]

[image]

Consider reaching the support of a developer and optimize it .. `gtmetrix` is a great source to check the areas that need improvement!